# How to refactor ninject over-injection to a more DRY form

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, scope, ninject

I would like to aggregate my injected objects into an Data object so that I don't have to have large constructor lists. However I still wish to use WhenInjectedInto to provide contextual binding.

For example the below spec tests a scenario that I believe will help

**WhenInjectedIntoRequestChain**

Indicates that the binding should only be used where the source 
has been injected been injected into parent0 which itself has been injected into parent1 and so on

The method should have the signiture

```
public static IBindingInNamedWithOrOnSyntax<T> 
        WhenInjectedIntoRequestChain<T>
            ( this IBindingWhenInNamedWithOrOnSyntax<T> @this
            , params Type[] parentChain
            )
```

The spec used to test this should be

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using FluentAssertions;
using Ninject;
using Weingartner.Controls.PluginFramework;
using Xunit;

namespace Weingartner.Controls.Spec.PluginFramework
{
    public class NinjectExtensionsSpec
    {
        public interface IData { }

        public class Data0 : IData {}
        public class Data1 : IData {}
        public class Data2 : IData {}

        public class Params
        {
            public IList<IData> Data { get; set; }

            public Params(IEnumerable<IData> data)
            {
                Data = data.ToList();
            }

        }

        public class Target0
        {
            public Params P { get; set; }
            public Target0(Params p) {P = p;}
        }

        public class Target1
        {
            public Params P { get; set; }
            public Target1(Params p){P = p;}
        }

        [Fact]
        public void WhenInjectedIntoHeirarchyShouldWork()
        {
            var k = new StandardKernel();

            k.Bind<IData>().To<Data0>()
             .WhenInjectedIntoRequestChain(typeof(Params),typeof(Target0));
            k.Bind<IData>().To<Data1>()
             .WhenInjectedIntoRequestChain(typeof(Params),typeof(Target1));
            k.Bind<IData>().To<Data2>()
             .WhenInjectedIntoRequestChain(typeof(Params),typeof(Target1));


            var target0 = k.Get<Target0>();
            var target1 = k.Get<Target1>();

            target0.P.Data.Count.Should().Be(1);
            target1.P.Data.Count.Should().Be(2);


        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution to the above problem with some test cases. It is not an exact solution for the above problem but this new method can solve the above.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using Ninject.Activation;
using Ninject.Infrastructure.Language;
using Ninject.Syntax;

namespace Weingartner.Controls.PluginFramework
{
    public static class NinjectExtensions
    {

        /// <summary>
        /// Indicates that the binding should only be used where the source 
        /// has been injected into parentChain[0] which in turn has been injected 
        /// into parentChain[1] and son on
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="parentChain">This list of parents in order</param>
        /// <returns>The fluent syntax.</returns>
        public static IBindingInNamedWithOrOnSyntax<T> 
            WhenInjectedIntoRequestChain<T>
                ( this IBindingWhenInNamedWithOrOnSyntax<T> @this
                , params Type[] parentChain
                )
        {

            @this.BindingConfiguration.Condition =
                request =>
                {
                    var result = true;
                    foreach (var parent in parentChain)
                    {
                        result = result && WhenInjectedInto(request, parent);
                        request = request?.ParentRequest;
                    }
                    return result;
                };

            return (IBindingInNamedWithOrOnSyntax<T>)@this;
        }

        private static bool WhenInjectedInto(IRequest request, Type parent)
        {
            if (!parent.IsGenericTypeDefinition)
                return request?.Target != null 
                    && parent.IsAssignableFrom(request.Target.Member.ReflectedType);

            if (!parent.IsInterface)
                return request
                    ?.Target?.Member.ReflectedType
                    .GetAllBaseTypes()
                    .Any(i => i.IsGenericType && i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == parent) 
                    ?? false;

            return request
                ?.Target?.Member.ReflectedType?
                .GetInterfaces()
                .Any(i => i.IsGenericType && i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == parent) 
                ?? false;
        }
    }
}
```